# Open Source Ad Server

Tags: open-source, advertisement-server

Is there any Open-Source Ad Server without Openx, because it doesn't have a Self-service account creation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I hear you about the self-service account feature. That's what I'm looking for as well.

I'm not sure if it has the feature, but here's another open source option: http://oasis.sourceforge.net

~~~

I saw in the OpenX docs that once you create your website entry, you can create individual user accounts for each advertiser.  However, I did not see a way where you can tell users they can sign up on their own for an ad account on your site.

Not sure if there's a big flaw with this approach yet, but one work around to get the self-service access with OpenX could be to write a bit of custom code that allows a registered user on your website to "activate their advertiser account".

When they click the link (plus whatever agreements), this could:

1. create a corresponding advertiser user in the OpenX database (bypassing the manual step that's necessary right now)
2. send out an email to the website user explaining he can now access his own ad campaign on your site, using the OpenX installation

It's a little hacky, but if we love everything else about OpenX, it seems like a low impact work around.

Comment: This project is dead. Last `update` **2007-11-27**

Answer (score 1):

FYI.
As of 08/05/2013 www.adserverbeans.com is not longer a valid URL.
The site indicates that the domain is for sale and there is no 
download for ASB MyAds.

Oasis 
http:// sourceforge.net/projects/oasis/
Is still available.

I found ASB MyAds at the following URLs:
http:// code.google.com/p/asb-myads/downloads/list
http:// sourceforge.net/projects/adserverbeans/

Answer (score -1):

If you were looking for a free service with self-service account creation why would care if it's open source?
If you are looking for open source software you obviously want to install/modify it and hence you can easily add account creation.

I represent ASB MyAds (http://www.adserverbeans.com) - an open source alternative to OpenX. We are creating a service based on it - OpenAdStore. Whether we need to have free account registration is still not clear. The objective is to let users get the feel of the product before they start buying it.

**EDIT:** The link above is no longer functional (as of 9th Dec 2012 it's a domain parking page).